# SQL Json Query With Variable

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to query SQL database with IMEI variable from android device, the variable is received (verified with log.txt), however whenever I replace '00000000000000' (android virtual device IMEI) with '$androidIMEI' the results are not returned but if I explicitly use the IMEI and not the variable I receive data.

```
<?php

include 'config.php';

$con=mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$dbname")or die("cannot select DB");

$androidIMEI = isset($_POST['IMEI']) ? $_POST['IMEI'] : '';

//$f = fopen("log.txt", "w");
//fwrite($f, print_r($androidIMEI, true));
//fclose($f); 

$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE Request = '0' AND IMEI = '000000000000000' ";
//$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE Request = '0' AND IMEI = '$androidIMEI ' "; //not working
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $json['users'][]=$row;
    }
}
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json); 
?>
```

Update: (printing SQL to log file)

```
$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE Request = '0' AND IMEI = '$androidIMEI'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$f = fopen("log.txt", "w");
fwrite($f, print_r($sql, true));
fclose($f);
```

Reading Log File:

```
SELECT * from users WHERE Request = '0' AND IMEI = '000000000000000'
```

AND THIS IS WHY I HAVE NO IDEA WHY IT IS NOT WORKING

Second Update:

This might be useful, code from android, how I'm sending my IMEI to PHP:

```
    class loadData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
            private StringBuilder sb;
            private ProgressDialog pr;
            private HttpResponse req;
            private InputStream is;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            }

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

                  ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();         

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("IMEI",IMEI));

                System.out.println("IMEI: "+IMEI);


                    try
                    {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mysite/myfile.php");
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();
                    InputStreamReader ireader = new InputStreamReader(is);
                    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(ireader);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");


                }
                    catch(Exception e)

                {

                    System.out.println("Error catch e");


                }
                    return id;     

            }
```

Comment: Do you see the value of `$_POST['IMEI']` when you `echo $sql;` using `$androidIMEI`?

Comment: I tried that and to my surprise I get: SELECT * from users WHERE Request = '0' AND IMEI = '000000000000000' which seems to be fine however it still doesn't work with: SELECT * from users WHERE Request = '0' AND IMEI = '$androidIMEI'

Comment: check the source (form) of the `$_POST['IMEI']` variable and make sure that it is sending the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Change
`"SELECT * from users WHERE Request = '0' AND IMEI = '$androidIMEI ' "` with `"SELECT * from users WHERE Request = '0' AND IMEI = '".$androidIMEI."' "`.

Also you are vulnerable for SQL injections. Do not use deprecated mysql_* functions and filter your input. More information at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

There is a `space` after `$androidIMEI` in your query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE Request = '0' AND IMEI = '$androidIMEI ' ";
```

should be

```
$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE Request = '0' AND IMEI = '$androidIMEI';";
```

Comment: the space was not the problem even after removing space

Answer (score 0):

Try this line

$sql = "SELECT * from users WHERE Request = '0' AND IMEI = '{$android}IMEI'";

I hope it will work.

Just note those curly braces.